# How to group by similar values with pg_trgm

Tags: postgresql, pg-trgm

I have the following table

```
id error
-  ----------------------------------------
1  Error 1234eee5, can not write to disk
2  Error 83457qwe, can not write to disk
3  Error 72344ee, can not write to disk
4  Fatal barier breach on object 72fgsff
5  Fatal barier breach on object 7fasdfa
6  Fatal barier breach on object 73456xcc5
```

I want to be able to get a result that counts by similarity, where similarity of > 80% means two errors are equal. I've been using pg_trgm extension, and its similarity function works perfectly for me, the only thing I can figure out how to produce the grouping result below.

```
Error                                  Count
-------------------------------------  ------
Error 1234eee5, can not write to disk, 3
Fatal barier breach on object 72fgsff, 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could join a table with itself to find similar strings, however this approach will end in a terribly slow query on a larger dataset. Also, using `similarity()` may cause inaccuracy in some cases (you need to find the appropriate limit value).

You should try to find patterns. For example, if all variable words in strings begin with a digit, you can mask them using `regexp_replace():`

```
select id, regexp_replace(error, '\d\w+', 'xxxxx') as error
from errors;

 id |                error                
----+-------------------------------------
  1 | Error xxxxx, can not write to disk
  2 | Error xxxxx, can not write to disk
  3 | Error xxxxx, can not write to disk
  4 | Fatal barier breach on object xxxxx
  5 | Fatal barier breach on object xxxxx
  6 | Fatal barier breach on object xxxxx
(6 rows)
```

so you can easily group the data by error message:

```
select regexp_replace(error, '\d\w+', 'xxxxx') as error, count(*)
from errors
group by 1;

                error                | count 
-------------------------------------+-------
 Error xxxxx, can not write to disk  |     3
 Fatal barier breach on object xxxxx |     3
(2 rows)
```

The above query is only an example as the specific solution depends on the data format.

### Using pg_trgm

The solution based on the OP's idea (see the comments below). The limit 0.8 for `similarity()` is certainly too high. It seems that it should be somewhere about 0.6.

The table for *unique* errors (I've used a temporary table but it also be a regular one of course):

```
create temp table if not exists unique_errors(
    id serial primary key, 
    error text, 
    ids int[]);
```

The `ids` column is to store `id` of rows of the base table which contain similar errors.

```
do $$
declare
    e record;
    found_id int;
begin
    truncate unique_errors;
    for e in select * from errors loop
        select min(id)
        into found_id
        from unique_errors u
        where similarity(u.error, e.error) > 0.6;
        if found_id is not null then
            update unique_errors
            set ids = ids || e.id
            where id = found_id;
        else
            insert into unique_errors (error, ids)
            values (e.error, array[e.id]);
        end if;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

The final results:

```
select *, cardinality(ids) as count
from unique_errors;

 id |                 error                 |   ids   | count 
----+---------------------------------------+---------+-------
  1 | Error 1234eee5, can not write to disk | {1,2,3} |     3
  2 | Fatal barier breach on object 72fgsff | {4,5,6} |     3
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this solution does not work for me, as its not generic enough.  query above requires maintenance of the sql query, there literally 100's of possible errors, above is just an example.  I could easily do this in python, just not familiar with sql looping constructs to write it out.

It would be like:
unique_errors = []
for row in "select error in errors":

Comment: I could easily do this in python, just not familiar with sql looping constructs to write it out.  The idea is to loop though each error, compare to list of unique_errors, if it hits similarity of 80% increment count in the unique list, if nothing is above 80% similarity, then add it to unique list with a count of 1, and proceed to the next error and so on until finished.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you could just group by left(error, 5), which would lead to two groups, one containing all the strings starting with Error, the other group containing all the strings starting with Fatal. This criteria would have to be updated if you are planning to add more error types.